# How to output a regex in a second file using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a template file `A.txt` (sep = `\t` ):

```
File Name   novaprime-ct043904-TB_2140.pcrd
Created By User admin
Notes   
ID  
Run Started 09/17/2020 01:19:12 UTC
Run Ended   09/17/2020 03:12:22 UTC
Sample Vol  30
Lid Temp    105
Protocol File Name  Cll Novaprime.prcl
Plate Setup File Name   CFX-TB_2140-20200916.pltd
Base Serial Number  CT043904
```

And a second file `B.txt` (sep = `\t`):

```
Cycle   Well    Value   Target  Content
1   A1  5.07368111264623    EC  Unkn-01
1   A1  3.06982862746599    FT  Unkn-09
1   A1  2.46545646544623    EC  Unkn-01
```

And I want to add an info from the 10th line of `A.txt` (what's in bold) to a new column in `B.txt`: `Plate Setup File Name   CFX-TB_2140-20200916.pltd`

In order to have `C.txt`(sep = `\t`):

```
Cycle   Well    Value   Target  Content Plate
1   A1  5.07368111264623    EC  Unkn-01 TB_2140
1   A1  3.06982862746599    FT  Unkn-09 TB_2140
1   A1  2.46545646544623    EC  Unkn-01 TB_2140
```

To do that I try various awk command using "-" as a separator but it didn't work. Do you have an idea how to do that ? Thanks

Comment: You could mention what you tried with `awk` so we can try to understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     NR==FNR {if (/^Plate Setup File Name/) {split($2,a,"-");id=a[2]};next}
     {if (FNR==1) $6="Plate"; else $6=id} 1' A.txt B.txt > C.txt
```

This will scan for a line "Plate Setup File Name" in `A.txt`, separate the value part into fields on `-`, and store the "Plate" part. When processing `B.txt`, it substitutes either a suitable header entry, or the plate ID.

Comment: Thanks. My problem washow to store the information. Now thanks to you I know how to do that

Comment: Consider writing that as `'NR==FNR { if (/^Plate Setup File Name/) {split($2,a,"-");id=a[2]} next} {$6= (FNR==1 ? "Plate" : id} 1'` as that'd get rid of both the redundant (e.g. the `next` and ```\``` in your code are doing nothing) and duplicate (referencing `$6` twice) code and improve the efficiency (removing the test for `NR>FNR`). You could also use `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` so you don't specify the same value (`\t`) in 2 separate statements.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, the `next` was actually from an attempt to make it shorter in the way you describe it; I somehow didn't finish it, must really get some coffee here ... As for your other comments: That would make the code more compact, but as you may have noticed, I often try to make it easier to read rather than "golfing" it. I do certainly agree that setting `FS` and `OFS` in the `BEGIN` section is more efficient, though.